# how can I remove white space in a string and replace it with (;) in batch

Tags: batch-file

How can I remove white space from this string or replace space with `;` in batch?

```
ECHO    V00000023903507 92  30573185    E28FC1  2015079 18-04-2015  27-04-2015  >>  %EXT%
```

I want it to look like this:

```
ECHO V00000017495345;90;30485020;FD2ECC;2015079;08-04-2015;19-04-2015 >> %EXT%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use delayed expansion and a `for` loop.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "str=    V00000023903507 92  30573185    E28FC1  2015079 18-04-2015  27-04-2015  "

set "fixed="
for %%I in (%str%) do (
    if not defined fixed (set "fixed=%%I") else set "fixed=!fixed!;%%I"
)

>>outfile.txt echo %fixed%
```

Or you could use [variable substring substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Replace).

```js
@echo off
setlocal

set "str=    V00000023903507 92  30573185    E28FC1  2015079 18-04-2015  27-04-2015  "

rem // replace tab with space (the blank character after : is a tab)
set "str=%str:  = %"

rem // replace all multiple spaces with single
set "str=%str:  = %"

rem // replace all spaces with ;
set "str=%str: =;%"

rem // remove first and last character
set "str=%str:~1,-1%"

>> outfile echo %str%
```